# Cylcling between two images to simulate animation in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create an animation to simulate a cartoon-ish athlete running. I have two different images of two states of the characters running position and I want to be able to cycle between the two images with roughly a 1 second delay between the image changing.

I have tried to do this through a storyboard changing the background of a canvas and have also  tried putting the two images on top of each other and changing the opacity from 0% -> 100% in a short space of time but either I'm missing something from my code to get it to work or I'm just going at the solution in the wrong direction.

Any help or links to possible solutions would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find anything to help me.

Hopefully this explains what I am looking for, but I can provide further details if needed.

EDIT: Okay, so I've taken the example provided by Noobacode and I have altered it to what I think should do what I need. I have the following:

**User control code behind**

```
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private int currentIndex = 1;
    private DispatcherTimer updateImageTimer;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.updateImageTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        this.updateImageTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30.0);
        this.updateImageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.updateImageTimer_Tick);

    }
    private void updateImageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(currentIndex == 1 )
        {
            backgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/blurredBackground1.png", UriKind.Relative));
            currentIndex++;
        }
        else if(currentIndex == 2)
        {
            backgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/blurredBackground2.png", UriKind.Relative));
            currentIndex--;
        }


    }
    public void Play()
    {
        updateImageTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        updateImageTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

**User control XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Going_For_Gold.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="492" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Stretch="Fill"/>

</Grid>
```

Now I have added the user control to my main window but image control I have placed into the main window (which I know is working correctly as if I put an initial image source into the UserControl I can see the image through the control on the main window) but this code doesn't seem to be updating the image source on tick.

Comment: Could you give us the code thus far?

Comment: I'm assuming you started the tick event? `this.updateImageTimer.Start();`  I see that you have Play() method, but do you ever use it?  Add some debugging code to see if the tick event fires off.

Comment: Yes, I am calling the .Start() method from the main window when the user presses a button. The tick event is running.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very clear explanation of **one** of the ways this can be accomplished:

http://dotnetslackers.com/XAML/re-192014_WPF_Image_Sequencer_for_animations.aspx

That link provides a good explanation of what's going on and there's also a complete source code.

**UPDATE:**

I'm not sure why it didn't for you, but let me provide a little bit simplified example.  I've tested it and it works just fine.

**STEP #1:**

Create a new User Control.  In the XAML portion, add `<Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Fill"/>`.  Here's how mine looks:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Animation"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**STEP #2:**

Go into code-behind of the User Control you've just created and add code similar to mine (do the same to start with and then adjust to your needs, so that you know it works):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Animation : UserControl
    {
        private int index = 1;
        private DispatcherTimer timer;

        public BitmapImage Image1 { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Image2 { get; set; }

        public Animation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Initiate()
        {
            if (Image1 != null && Image2 != null)
            {
                image.Source = Image1;

                this.timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
                this.timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0);
                this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.updateImage);
                this.timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void updateImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (index == 1)
            {
                image.Source = Image2;
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                image.Source = Image1;
                index--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set 1 second interval for the animation.

**STEP #3:**

In whatever window you're planning on adding this control, add the appropriate namespace and the control in XAML, here's my example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:Animation x:Name="animation" Width="400" Height="350"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**STEP #4:**

In the code-behind for that window, add this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadSourceImages();
        }

        private void LoadSourceImages()
        {
            animation.Image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pictures\image1.jpg"));
            animation.Image2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pictures\image2.jpg"));
            animation.Initiate();
        }
    }
}
```

I made it so that you can change background images for the animation from outside of the control.  That code is not perfect from the MVVM perspective, but it's a good start.  Try my code first, then, if it works, adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I have updated my original question with code for my attempt at using that example for my solution. However, I'm have issues with updating the UserControl image source on each tick.

Comment: What sort of issues?  I know your'e new to StackOverflow, but this tip will generally help you down the road:  be specific.  Describe what is occurring and what you're having issues with.  Being vague, such as, "I'm having issues" or "It's not working" will not help you.  Also, have you read the article in the link provided?  It'll give a better explanation of what's going on.  Also, take a look at their source code provided, since it's a whole project and you can compare any differences.

Comment: To add, an issue could be that you didn't start the tick event: `this.updateImageTimer.Start();`

Comment: Sorry, I did put my issues and the code in the edit of my original question as it was a bit much for the comment box. I have the ticker start on a button click event in the main window.

Comment: @user3280835 Can you check with the debugger if the tick event is working properly?  Post some messages into debugger each time tick happens: `Debug.WriteLine("Tick Event");`  Always work out->in.  When a light is not working, check the power source soft-of-thing.

Comment: So, next, check your `if` and `else if` statements.  Make sure those alternate each tick event.  Use debug for that as well.

Comment: The if and else are both working correctly. It must be in issue with setting the image source.

Comment: I have figured it out now, I was using calling the method incorrectly. In my main window I had the following:
`UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
 control.Play();`
But it needed to be just:
`userControl.Play();`
Where user control is the name of the UserControl in the main window XAML.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a UserControl. In the control overlap two Images together. In code behind you use a DispatcherTimer to flip the Visibility of the two (or more) images. Then you can reuse this control anywhere you want to show an animation.